# All of my renders are going pink, without textures being an issue. I reassigned materials yet they are still rendering wrong. Blender 3.4.1

Tags: rendering, materials

[image][image]

I'm not sure what the problem is. I downloaded a 3d file from a free website, I reassigned the materials to the object, and chose a black diffuse shader. Hit render, and this happens. I've included pictures, and a file to download if you need it.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/dftgd1swa6gcv7g/chainlink_fence_2.blend/file

Answer (score 1):

The world environment texture is missing :
[image]